# How to change the border thickness in mouseover

Tags: .net, silverlight, styles, blend

I'm working on the styles of controls. I want to change the borderthickness of a control when the mouseover is done. I want to write this in the style itself instead of writing it in codebehind

So, I tried in the following way.

```
<VisualState x:Name="MouseOver">
<Storyboard>
<DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Border" Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderThickness">
<SplineDoubleKeyFrame  KeyTime="0" Value="2" />                                   
</DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
</Storyboard>
</VisualState>
```

But this is throwing an error.

How can I achieve this functionality.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames` instead `DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames` in your case:

```
<ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Border" Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderThickness">
    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="2"/>
</ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
```

`DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames` animates the value of a `Double` property, whereas `BorderThickness` is type of `Thickness`, not `Double`.