# Is it possible to style BorderThickness of RadioButton?

Tags: xaml, silverlight, border

I'd like to change the BorderThickness of a RadioButton. Is this possible?
This is what I've got so far:

```
<Style TargetType="RadioButton">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="RadioButton">
                    <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
                        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Normal">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderThickness" Storyboard.TargetName="Border">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="6" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                            <!-- ... -->        
                        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>             
                    </Border>                   
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

I read this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12143099/how-to-change-the-border-thickness-in-mouseover) but somehow it's not working for me because:

> The name "ThicknessAnimation" does not exist in the namespace "http://schemas.microsoft.com/client/2007"

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question: yes, it is possible to style the `BorderThickness` of the `RadioButton` control.
In what context do you want to change the `BorderThickness`?
In order to have one particular button show a thicker border just set the property accordingly:

```
<RadioButton x:Name="MyNiceFoobarButton" BorderThickness="6"/>
```

If you want all your RadioButtons to have a thicker border you have to use a `Style`:

```
<Style TargetType="RadioButton">
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="6"/>
</Style>
```

[Edit]
And if you want your button to show a thicker border only while a paticular `VisualState` is active you have to overwrite the `ControlTemplate` and specify all `VisualStates` with their corresponding animations.